# Arduino Tian ser2net configuration

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide

I am trying to upload a sketch to the Arduino via Network and then open also the Serial monitor. While for the first task I've a solution, how to open the Serial monitor is still unknown to me.

Usually when connected to the same WiFi network, the Arduino should appear on the "network port list" in the Arduino IDE but for some reasons it does not (or not always).

I am therefore looking for an alternative solution and I've found the package *ser2net* but I don't know how to configure it for my case.

The situation is the following:

```
Arduino(WiFi AP) -----WiFi------ Laptop

192.168.1.1                    192.168.1.2
```

The devices can correctly communicate and I can access the Arduino through SSH.

Here's the description of Tian's serial:

"Serial: 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). Used to receive (RX) and transmit (TX) 3.3V serial data using the Atmel SAMD21 hardware serial capability. Note that on the Tian, the Serial class refers to USB (CDC) communication; for 3.3V serial on pins 0 and 1, use the Serial5 class. The hardware serials of the Atmel SAMD21 and the AR9342 on the Tian are connected together and are used to communicate between the two processors via SerialUSB."

**EDIT:**

The reply I gave is partially true.
It is true that works how I've explained but only if the sketch on the Arduino is an easy one, for example just printing something every 2 seconds.

Since I want to interact between the microcontroller and the microprocessor, the sketch is using the Ciao class.
This generates another issue: in the monitor over network, also the control commands of the Ciao library are shown and these are then interpret as Serial input and this leads to an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get things working.
On arduino I run this

```
ser2net -C "8082:raw:600:/dev/ttySAMD:115200 NONE 1STOPBIT 8DATABITS -XONXOFF -LOCAL -RTSCTS"
```

then with Putty (I'm using Windows 10), raw connection to 192.168.1.1 on port 8082 and the Serial Monitor will appear.

The arduino sketch uses *SerialUSB* instead of *Serial*.